# Get one row in a Many To Many table via Table column

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

If I have a Many To Many Table

Say

```
Users
Roles
Role_User
```

A Role has a name. The Role_User contains a pivot value namely "value".

How could I easily retrieve "one" role by name from the User's roles and get the pivot data as well?

Like:

```
$attr = $user->getRole('Admin');

$attr->pivot->value;
```

A foreach may work, but it seems like there is a more effective way? no?

Answer (score 0):

When you define your relationship you need to define the columns you want to also pull in from the pivot table.

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role')->withPivot('value');
}
```

Now, not sure if this is the best way but if you know the ID of the role it would make it a whole lot easier.

```
$role = $user->roles()->find(1); // Where 1 is the ID of the admin role

dd($role->pivot->value);
```

The docs have more about [working with pivot tables](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables).

Comment: Yep I know, I want to query the attribute via name The "role" table has a "name" field that is instead. Possible?

Comment: Instead of find you'd use a standard `where` and then `first` to get a single record.